# Word meaning 'common line of reasoning for a given issue'.

Tags: single-word-requests

For example

> A common [word] espoused by climate change deniers is that global temperatures haven't increased for ten years, and thus anthropocentric climate change is not real.

Comment: ***line*** **5.2** A manner of doing or thinking about something: *the superintendent was thinking along the same lines* http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/line However, *espoused* does not fit the context.

Comment: The word _theory_ would fit there, but is more general than just a line of reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

[Argument](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/argument): a course of reasoning aimed at demonstrating truth or falsehood; fact or statement put forth as proof or evidence; a reason; a set of statements in which one follows logically as a conclusion from the others.

> - A popular argument of climate change deniers is that the Earth's warming and cooling over millions of years is not connected with... The Guardian
> - One argument of climate change deniers is the fact that many of the extremes we're seeing: Heat... Nature.com

*Argument* stresses the advancement by each side of facts and reasons intended to persuade the other side.

You can also use *position*.

Answer (score 1):

Dogma is a principle or set of principles laid down by an authority as incontrovertibly true.[1] It serves as part of the primary basis of an ideology or belief system, and it cannot be changed or discarded without affecting the very system's paradigm, or the ideology itself. The term can refer to acceptable opinions of philosophers or philosophical schools, public decrees, religion, or issued decisions of political authorities

~[2], "Dogma" The Concise Oxford Dictionary of World Religions. Ed. John Bowker. Oxford University Press, 2000. Oxford Reference Online. Oxford University Press. York University. 25 October 2011 http://www.oxfordreference.com.ezproxy.library.yorku.ca/views/ENTRY.html?subview=Main&entry=t101.e2044.

Answer (score 0):

In the example sentence given in the question, previously-suggested *[argument](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/argument#Noun)* is highly suitable.  But in other instances of a “common line of reasoning for a given issue”, the following terms may apply:

> • *[paradigm](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paradigm#Noun)*, in its sense “A system of assumptions, concepts, values, and practices that constitutes a way of viewing reality” or its sense “A conceptual framework—an established thought process”
>   • *[mindset](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mindset#Noun)*, “A way of thinking; an attitude or opinion, especially a habitual one”
>   • *[party line](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/party_line)*, “The official policy of a political party or other organization”
>   • *[received wisdom](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/received%20opinion)* (or *received opinion*) “generally accepted or believed”

Answer (score 0):

To the list of related words according to the context I'd add:

[Interpretation:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/interpret)

> 1. clarification or explanation of the meaning of; elucidation
> 2. construction of  the significance or intention of: to interpret a smile as an invitation.
> 3. An explanation or conceptualization by a critic of a work of literature, painting, music, or other art form; an exegesis.

Answer (score -1):

[Theme](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/theme):

> A topic of discourse or discussion.
>
> An implicit or recurrent idea; a motif.